# how do you sum time values in listview?

Tags: c#, listview

I have a `listview` setup in c#, one of the columns contains values for time. I want to know how i would go about summing these.

I currently have some code whereby clicking a button sums the decimal values in another column and wonder if this can be manipulated to suit time.

```
private void buttonListTotal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double grandtotalPower = 0;
    //TimeSpan grandtotalTime = 
    foreach (ListViewItem lstItem in listView1.Items)
    {
        grandtotalPower += double.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[1].Text);
    }
    textBoxListTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(grandtotalPower);
}
```

Comment: how did you try to use `grandtotalTime`?

Comment: i tried setting it equal to 0 and 00:00:00, but the program didn't like it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly shows how your control is initialized and how you want to sum the values, it's impossible to know for sure what is the best answer.

That said, a couple of points:

- You can initialize a "zero" `TimeSpan` value simply by using `new TimeSpan()`. E.g. `TimeSpan grandtotalTime = new TimeSpan();`.
- You can parse elapse time values using `TimeSpan.Parse()`, similarly as you're doing with `double.Parse()`.

So, assuming the column values in your case are text (same as for the `double` values you're already summing), the code would look something like this:

```
private void buttonListTotal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan grandtotalTime = new TimeSpan();
    foreach (ListViewItem lstItem in listView1.Items)
    {
        // Use the correct SubItems[] index for your time values, of course,
        // and not the "1" that was in your double-based code.
        grandtotalTime += TimeSpan.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[1].Text);
    }
    textBoxListTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(grandtotalTime );
}
```

Obviously if your actual scenario deviates from the `double`-based example you provided, the above would need to be adjusted to suit. But the basic idea will be the same.

Comment: Glad you found it helpful. Please feel free to mark as "accepted" the answer which you feel best addresses your question :)

Answer (score 1):

you need first to convert thedatain subitems[1] to timespan
          ex.

```
        TimeSpan grandtotalTime = new TimeSpan();
        TimeSpan ts;
         foreach (ListViewItem lstItem in listView1.Items)
           {

           ts = TimeSpan.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[1].Text);
           grandtotalTime += ts; 
            }
             textBoxListTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(grandtotalTime );
              }
```

I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Is the time values in those columns a time span? If that is the case then set

```
var grandTotalTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
```

Then convert your time values to whatever units they are and add them to your grandTotalTime.